# iOS Swift Linker Command Failed with exit code1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build the iPhone App that used to work on GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). However now Google uses Firebase Cloud Messaging. I have used the tutorial from Google Firebase but did not help at all. Here are the things that I have completed before I asked this question.

1. Install Pod Firebase
2. Clean Project and Build :( nope doesn't work.
3. Researched for similar errors on Google and applied to my project:) nope didn't work.

I really need help on this issue. Error code:

```
 Ld /Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Intermediates/BestKebab.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Oyeskebab.build/Objects-normal/i386/Oyeskebab normal i386
    cd "/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST\ KEBAB/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -filelist /Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Intermediates/BestKebab.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Oyeskebab.build/Objects-normal/i386/Oyeskebab.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGcmLib -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleIPhoneUtilities -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MessageUI -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Intermediates/BestKebab.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Oyeskebab.build/Objects-normal/i386/Oyeskebab.swiftmodule -lPods-Oyeskebab -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Intermediates/BestKebab.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Oyeskebab.build/Objects-normal/i386/Oyeskebab_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ProWebDesign/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BestKebab-ejzmykmprlhmpmbxusvdbwegnebw/Build/Intermediates/BestKebab.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Oyeskebab.build/Objects-normal/i386/Oyeskebab

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpAudienceRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpAudienceRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeEnumDescriptor in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeEnumDescriptor in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeEnumDescriptor in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeEnumDescriptor in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPPropertyFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPPropertyFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPStringFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPStringFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPFilter in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeIsValidValue in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeIsValidValue in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPAudience in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPAudience in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_28da55a8ccea24070c425af5bb70cfc8.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpConfigRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpConfigRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPSetting in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPSetting in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventConfig in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventConfig in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementConfig in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementConfig in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_b51e6ed85781e3207898dc567b9243b1.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpMeasurementRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpMeasurementRoot in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEvent in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEvent in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPAudienceLeafFilterResult in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPAudienceLeafFilterResult in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventParam in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventParam in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBatch in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBatch in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPUserAttribute in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPUserAttribute in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBundle in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBundle in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPResultData in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPResultData in:
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
    /Users/ProWebDesign/Desktop/BEST KEBAB/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_d4d9785b6ddcc58cf9d042a5a1d1e756.o)
ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It's because of the `Firebase Analytics` framework. I had to remove the framework and am currently waiting for them to update the framework

Comment: Or you might just have to add the `i386` architecture in build settings for your target

Comment: I did try to instal architecture i386 doesn't help. Will it work if i delete the framework?

Comment: Mine did and I would think so. If you do, keep note of the one(s) you delete

Comment: I deleted the framework for analytics but still same issue.

Comment: Does it work on an actual device?

Comment: No it doesn't pass the build phase.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not really sure what else to suggest. Did you add the ObjC linked flag to the target?

Comment: OBJC uses $(inherit)

Comment: @Nik hey nik , i am also experiencing the same problem , can you tell me how to remove the firebase analytics framework ?? should i delete the folder or any other way to remove it ??

Comment: @narahari_arjun To delete the framework, you can just remove the folder (remove reference if it's a reference, actually delete it if it's a copy). Keep note of any frameworks you remove for when you want to add them back though

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I also had the GoogleAnalytics framework imported. After removing the Google/Analytics pod and installing it again, it magically started working.