# How to remove firebase analytics dependencies from xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I want to use firebase in my iOS App, I have installed the pod Firebase/Core and Google/CloudMessaging and the following dependencies got installed

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (3.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.5.1)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.4.4)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Installing GGLInstanceID (1.2.1)
Installing Google (2.0.4)
Installing GoogleCloudMessaging (1.2.0)
Installing GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.3.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Now when I'm running my project it gives me an error

Error stack trace:

```
/Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCMTestDemo.app/GCMTestDemo
 normal x86_64
     cd "/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo"
     export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk
 -L/Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
 -L/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries
 -L/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries
 -L/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
 -F/Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone\ Test\ Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
 -filelist /Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Intermediates/GCMTestDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCMTestDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCMTestDemo.LinkFileList
 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker
 -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGcmLib -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreFoundation
 -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore
framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleIPhoneUtilities -framework
 GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities
 -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MessageUI -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
 -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Intermediates/GCMTestDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCMTestDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCMTestDemo.swiftmodule
 -framework Pods_GCMTestDemo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Intermediates/GCMTestDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCMTestDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCMTestDemo_dependency_info.dat
 -o /Users/arjunnarahari/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCMTestDemo-ctamygrxtrevhdfxelpouoirwdsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCMTestDemo.app/GCMTestDemo

 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpAudienceRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpAudienceRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol
 _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeEnumDescriptor in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol
 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeEnumDescriptor in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeEnumDescriptor
 in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol
 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeEnumDescriptor in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPPropertyFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPPropertyFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPNumberFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPStringFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPStringFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPFilter in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _ACPNumberFilter_ComparisonTypeIsValidValue in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _ACPStringFilter_MatchTypeIsValidValue in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPAudience in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPAudience in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpAudience.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpAudience.pb_9c6ef258637178a5b66fafe47116db3f.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpConfigRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpConfigRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPSetting in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPSetting in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventConfig in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventConfig in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementConfig in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementConfig in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpConfig.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpConfig.pb_6c87558aa22418a390275a3b1c6c3240.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPGmpMeasurementRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPGmpMeasurementRoot in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEvent in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEvent in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPAudienceLeafFilterResult in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPAudienceLeafFilterResult in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPEventParam in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPEventParam in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBatch in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBatch in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPUserAttribute in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPUserAttribute in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBundle in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPMeasurementBundle in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPResultData in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPResultData in:
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o)
     /Users/arjunnarahari/Iphone Test Projects/GCMTestDemo/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_0160b3b2a6af7db9055875e2a39091bf.o)
 ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
 command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found one solution here which is similar to mine
[iOS Swift Linker Command Failed with exit code1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458017/ios-swift-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code1)

So now my question is how to remove only the firebaseanalytics dependencies from the project? Or any other solution for removing the error will also work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the answer after some hard searching , i had installed two pods 
1. Firebase/Core
2. Google/CloudMessaging

I deleted both from nano podfile and updated it with Firebase/Messaging and did pod update and the error vanished.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Have you been able to use the GCM after this or you had to rewrite the notification handling in your application?